# long long int values are incorrectly printed

Tags: c, embedded, arm, gcc4.7

When I cross compile an application for target with an Armv7 core,  variables with 'long long int' are incorrectly printed.

```
typedef long long int vmm_int64;
typedef unsigned long long int vmm_uint64;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vmm_int64 a, b, result;

    a = 5;
    b = 24;
    result = 0;

    printf("Initial Values are:\n");
    printf("\t a : %lld \n", a);
    printf("\t b : %lld \n", b);
    printf("\t result : %lld \n", result);

    fflush(stdout);

    result = a + b;

    printf("Final Values are:\n");
    printf("\t a : %lld \n", a);
    printf("\t b : %lld \n", b);
    printf("\t result : %lld \n", result);

    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Initial Values are:
     a : 23639177792
     b : 105243556416
     result : 2164341312
Final Values are:
     a : 23639177792
     b : 105243556416
     result : 126718392896
```

Could someone please explain what is going on here?  What should I do to make it right?

After some more analysis, I just observed that

```
a = 0x5 (0x00000005 81013a44  which is hex for  23639177792)
b = 0x18 (0x00000018 81013a40 which is hex for 105243556416)

i. result = 0 (0x00000000 81013a40 which is hex for 2164341312)
ii. result = 0x1D (0x0000001D 81013a40 which is hex for 126718392896)
```

The upper 32 bits contain the correct values.  I just don't understand why

1. The result is upper/lower word swapped.
2. Even if the words were swapped, why is there junk in the lower word.

Compiler info:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\Program Files\CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/program files/codesourcery/sourcery g++ lite/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.5.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/src/gcc-4.5-2011.03/configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi --enable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-extra-sgxxlite-multilibs --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-specs='%{save-temps: -fverbose-asm} -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MAJ__=2011 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_MIN__=3 -D__CS_SOURCERYGXX_REV__=42 %{O2:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}} %{O*:%{O|O0|O1|O2|Os:;:%{!fno-remove-local-statics: -fremove-local-statics}}}' --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-shared --enable-lto --with-newlib --with-pkgversion='Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-42' --with-bugurl=https://support.codesourcery.com/GNUToolchain/ --disable-nls --prefix=/opt/codesourcery --with-headers=yes --with-sysroot=/opt/codesourcery/arm-none-eabi --with-build-sysroot=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/install/host-i686-mingw32/arm-none-eabi --with-libiconv-prefix=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/host-libs-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/usr --with-gmp=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/host-libs-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/usr --with-mpfr=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/host-libs-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/usr --with-mpc=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/host-libs-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/usr --with-ppl=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/host-libs-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-cloog=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/host-libs-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/usr --with-libelf=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/host-libs-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/usr --disable-libgomp --enable-poison-system-directories --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/tools-i686-pc-linux-gnu-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/arm-none-eabi/bin --with-build-time-tools=/scratch/janisjo/arm-eabi-lite/obj/tools-i686-pc-linux-gnu-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-mingw32/arm-none-eabi/bin
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.5.2 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-42)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you `#include`'ing `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: I am getting : Initial Values are:
  a : 5 
  b : 24 
  result : 0 
Final Values are:
  a : 5 
  b : 24 
  result : 29

Comment: The code has been cross-compiled using G++ for ARM from Code Sourcery.

Comment: @Girish Why are you compiling C code with a C++ compiler?

Comment: @H2CO3 This one supports both C & C++ (Sourcery G++ Lite cross compiler).  It works predictably for 32 bits and less.

Comment: @Girish No. C++ compilers don't support C (unless they have a dedicated C mode which g++ hasn't). The fact that C and C++ share a somewhat common "subset" doesn't mean that you could or should treat C code as C++, because it isn't. In addition, compiling C++ is more difficult than compiling C - if there's a compiler bug, then it will more likely be in the C++ compiler, and not in the C one. **Compile your code with `gcc` instead of `g++`.**

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes,  I do use gcc (arm-none-eabi-gcc) as the compiler command. It comes in a suite that has G++.

Comment: @Girish Ah OK. Then I misunderstood you, sorry for that.

Comment: @H2CO3; What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18272802/2455888) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18273005/2455888) ?

Comment: @haccks Those are wrong non-answers.

Comment: @haccks Voted down and for deletion; flagged as "not an answer" as well.

Comment: @H2c03:  In fact g++ and gcc are almost identical compiler drivers that differ only in their defaults. The g++ compiler driver *by default* links libc++. Equally gcc can be switched to explicitly link libc++.  All you need for either to compile C or C++ is an appropriate source file extension, or command line switch.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're mixing ABIs. Probably your cross compiler is using APCS (aka Old ABI) while Android runtime expects EABI.

One important difference between the two is how 64-bit values are passed in registers. Old ABI uses the next available pair of registers, e.g.

```
; printf("\t a : %lld \n", a);
load format string into R0
load 'a' into R1 and R2
call printf
```

while EABI uses the next *even-aligned* register pair:

```
; printf("\t a : %lld \n", a);
load format string into R0
load 'a' into R2 and R3
call printf
```

Let's look how `a` would be passed for both ABIs:

<strike>1. Actual: 5 = 0 (high32) and 5 (low32)</strike>

OABI: R1 = 0, R2 = 5
  EABI: R2 = 0, R3 = 5

1. Printed: 23639177792 = 0x581013A40 = 0x5 (high32) and 0x81013A40 (low32)

   OABI: R1 = 5, R2 = 0x81013A40
   EABI: R2 = 5, R3 = 0x81013A40

So most likely your code loaded 0 into `R1` and 5 into `R2`, but `printf` interpreted `R2` as the high part and garbage from `R3` as the low part. You can easily check it by inspecting the generated assembly.

The fix should be easy - use a compiler option to generate **EABI** code, or just use a toolchain which specifically targets Android, e.g. Android NDK.

**EDIT**: I had the high and low parts swapped. Here's the correct version:

1. Actual: 5 = 0 (high32) and 5 (low32)

   OABI: R1 = 5, R2 = 0
   EABI: R2 = 5, R3 = 0
2. Printed: 23639177792 = 0x581013A40 = 0x5 (high32) and 0x81013A40 (low32)

   OABI: R1 = 0x81013A40, R2 = 5
   EABI: R2 = 0x81013A40, R3 = 5

So, the evidence actually suggests the opposite: your code is using EABI while `printf` is expecting OABI.

Comment: That seems more reasonable.  I just had a look at the disassembly.  Here's how it goes.                                          `printf("\t a : %lld \n", a);    movs r2, #0x5       movs r3,#0x0       ldr r0, 0x800104d4       bl 0x80015b00      (which goes to the print libray function)`

Comment: from your comment I infer that EABI is the current mode of the compiler

Comment: Where does your `printf` come from? Is it a system library (bionic) or something provided by the toolchain? Try compiling with `-v -Wl,--verbose` to see which libraries are being pulled in and try to track down `printf` code.

Comment: The printf comes as part of the RTOS package. Its not the one supplied by the toolchain.

Comment: Okay, then it sounds like the RTOS binaries were complied for old ABI, so you'll need a matching compiler. Though you can try playing with the [`-mabi=` switch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html).

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000149/a-puzzle-about-hook-arm-function-by-modify-elf-file), except the question was a little more complex had an answer like this.  I think you are on the right track, but `printf` is varargs, so I think things are on the stack?  This can also be the problem, if the root cause isn't even/odd register numbers.  Both stem from `ldrd` and `strd`.

Comment: @Girish: If the third-party library you are using is not fully C99 compliant, it may not support 64 bit integers.  I have come across older implementations that silently accept the format specifier without actually supporting the data type.  Check the library documentation or at least be clear about whose library and what version this is so that others might investigate.

Comment: @artlessnoise: That seems to be possible solution. But I am unable to make head or tail of it and less open to making changes to the binary.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: The RTOS comes in a source code bundle from the vendor. ( I could not give more info about the vendor, though :( ). So, i guess that building the source code should yield the binary with EABI format.

Comment: @Clifford: Tested the same after compiling with `-std=gnu99`.  The result was the same.  Is this the right way to build it with C99 compliance?

Comment: Try the following `printf("\t%s a : %lld \n", "", a);`.  This will add an unused `char *`, so that the registers are in the correct order.  If that doesn't work, then you can add some more unused stack/local variables.  This should allow you to deduce which problem it is.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Add the above `printf` code immediately below `printf("\t a: %lld \n", a);`  The above test resulted in `a : 23639177792     a : -9220059882630152192`. Tried adding some more unused variables after that `printf("\t%s%s a: %lld \n", "", "", a);`.  This gave me the result as `a : 23639177792       a : 0     a : 21474836489`

Comment: I don't believe it is **OABI** versus **EABI**, if that is the case.  Did you try to put more local variables on the stack?  That is sort of the same issue.  It does look like the `printf` is getting an address as part of the `%lld`.

Comment: @Girish:  It is not a matter of compiling for C99, that would not change how the library behaves.